# Add printer to CUPS using API

Tags: cups

Is there a way to add a bunch of printers to CUPS via API?
I have CUPS server running in docker and have a list of printers I need to add there with specific drives. CUPS docks do not answer this question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

actually, you can add a printer to cups by command, like:

`lpadmin -p "printerName" -E -v lpd://192.168.1.2/queue -P driver.ppd`

the details of `lpadmin` cups api, check this out:

https://github.com/apple/cups/blob/master/systemv/lpadmin.c

Comment: That is a pretty old question )))

Comment: Anyways lpadmin is not a good choice for CUPS in docker. I am during IPP